# Comparing two files or why this code in Java is faster than C++?

Tags: java, c++, file, ifstream

Why this code in Java is faster than C++?
I need to compare 2 files byte by byte.
For example when comparing two files size 650mb takes 40 seconds to C++ and 10 seconds for Java.

C++ code:

```
//bufferSize = 8mb
std::ifstream lFile(lFilePath.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
std::ifstream rFile(rFilePath.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

std::streamsize lReadBytesCount = 0;
std::streamsize rReadBytesCount = 0;

do {
    lFile.read(p_lBuffer, *bufferSize);
    rFile.read(p_rBuffer, *bufferSize);
    lReadBytesCount = lFile.gcount();
    rReadBytesCount = rFile.gcount();

    if (lReadBytesCount != rReadBytesCount ||
        std::memcmp(p_lBuffer, p_rBuffer, lReadBytesCount) != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
} while (lFile.good() || rFile.good());

return true;
```

And Java code:

```
InputStream is1 = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f1)); 
InputStream is2 = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f2)); 

byte[] buffer1 = new byte[64];
byte[] buffer2 = new byte[64];

int readBytesCount1 = 0, readBytesCount2 = 0;

while (
    (readBytesCount1 = is1.read(buffer1)) != -1 &&
    (readBytesCount2 = is2.read(buffer2)) != -1
) {             
    if (Arrays.equals(buffer1, buffer2) && readBytesCount1 == readBytesCount2)
        countItr++;
    else {
        result = false
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you make the buffers the same size?

Comment: Have you eliminated file caching as a possible contributing factor?

Comment: when the buffers the same code in C++ works still longer.

Comment: Different isn't the same. -- Fred Picker.

Comment: What kind of test machine are you using? On my rather slow rig your c++ code takes about 10 seconds, if nothing else is running. With some IO in the background it can easily go up to 30 seconds. Can't be bothered with Java unless you post a complete program.

Comment: The two blocks of code even differ in when they stop -- one uses or and the other and.  If you want good answers, create self contained, complete compiling examples.  And fully describe the test (what steps you took in what order).  Thus allowing others to reproduce your results, which people below are finding difficult.

Comment: I've made some working examples, trying to use as much of their code as possible: https://gist.github.com/xymostech/5072238 I've found that no matter what I do, the C++ one goes faster for me.

Comment: The code you are showing is not the code you are running. There is something about the examples that are different other than what you are showing us. Otherwise these results make no sense.

Comment: In fact, if I lower the buffer size, then depending on the mood of the cache it can take as low as 1.5 seconds.

Answer (score 10):

One possible answer could be that the C++ code uses a buffer of 8 Mb, while the Java version uses 64 bytes. What happens if the difference is within the first few bytes? then the Java version needs to only read 64 bytes, to find the difference, while the C++ version needs to read 8 million. If you wish to compare them you should really use the same buffer size.

Further more, if the files are identical, there can be other reasons for the difference. Consider the time it takes to allocate 8 mb of data (this could even span across multiple pages), versus the time it takes to simply allocate 64 bytes. Since you are reading sequentially, the overhead is really on the memory side.

Comment: Сomparing two **identical** file size 650 MB takes 40 seconds and 10 seconds for Java.

Comment: @Silnet if they are identical, you still have a huge overhead in allocating the memory, perhaps the memory even spans across multiple pages.

Comment: This is a bogus argument, reading 8 MB takes no time on current hardware, let alone 10 or 40 seconds.

Comment: I dont have any experience in C++ , but wouldnt be it faster in C++ as you have the full memory at your doorstep as in Java which has a limit as defined by the Java parameters ?

Comment: @user1428716 If you wish to compare two languages, give them equal terms. There are other differences in the program, but this is one of the more significant.

Answer (score 1):

I just took your Java program and wrote an equivalent C++ program and both take nearly the same to compare two identical files, give or take a second.

One possible, trivial, explanation is that you ran the C++ program first and then the Java program. If this was your only test, the difference in execution time can be explained by just caching, although 40 seconds are a lot of time for reading 650 MB on today's hardware.

The data blocks are in the system file cache, and the second time there was no disk access to retrieve the files. In order to get comparable results, run the tests multiple times with the C++ and the Java program.

In your code, you have

```
lFile.read(p_lBuffer, *bufferSize);
```

which contradicts your comment at the beginning

```
//bufferSize = 8mb
```

so unless you show real *complete* code, anyone's guess is valid.

To eat my own dog food

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

const size_t N = 8 * 1024 * 1024;
char buf1[N], buf2[N];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::iostream::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::ifstream f1(argv[1]);
    std::ifstream f2(argv[2]);
    while (f1.read(buf1, sizeof(buf1)) && f2.read(buf2, sizeof(buf2))) {
        size_t n1 = f1.gcount(), n2 = f2.gcount();
        if (n1 != n2 || memcmp(buf1, buf2, n1) != 0)
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the buffer size answer is a really good one, and likely very important, another possible source of your problem is using the `iostream` library. I would generally not use that library for this sort of work. One issue this could be causing, for example, is extra copying because of the buffering that `iostream` does for you. I would use the raw `read` and `write` calls.

For example, on a Linux C++11 platform I would do this:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

// Needed for open and close on a Linux platform
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using ::std::string;

bool same_contents(const string &fname1, const string &fname2)
{
   int fd1 = ::open(fname1.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
   if (fd1 < 0) {
      throw ::std::runtime_error("Open of " + fname1 + " failed.");
   }
   int fd2 = ::open(fname2.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
   if (fd2 < 0) {
      ::close(fd1);
      fd1 = -1;
      throw ::std::runtime_error("Open of " + fname2 + " failed.");
   }

   bool same = true;
   try {
      ::std::array<char, 4096> buf1;
      ::std::array<char, 4096> buf2;
      bool done = false;

      while (!done) {
         int read1 = ::read(fd1, buf1.data(), buf1.size());
         if (read1 < 0) {
            throw ::std::runtime_error("Error reading " + fname1);
         }
         int read2 = ::read(fd2, buf2.data(), buf2.size());
         if (read2 < 0) {
            throw ::std::runtime_error("Error reading " + fname2);
         }
         if (read1 != read2) {
            same = false;
            done = true;
         }
         if (same && read1 > 0) {
            const auto compare_result = ::std::mismatch(buf1.begin(),
                                                        buf1.begin() + read1,
                                                        buf2.begin());
            if (compare_result.first != (buf1.begin() + read1)) {
               same = false;
            }
         }
         if (!same || (buf1.size() > read1)) {
            done = true;
         }
      }
   } catch (...) {
      if (fd1 >= 0) ::close(fd1);
      if (fd2 >= 0) ::close(fd2);
      throw;
   }
   if (fd1 >= 0) ::close(fd1);
   if (fd2 >= 0) ::close(fd2);
   return same;
}
```